# TensorFlow Keras API - Found 0 images belonging to 2 classes

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I need assistance with my code to figure out where the problem is.I am having a challenge moving the cat and dog images into the train,test and validation folder which are inside the Dogs-vs-Cats Folder.I get this message:

```
Found 0 images belonging to 2 classes. 
Found 0 images belonging to 2 classes. 
Found 0 images belonging to 2 classes.
```

Below are mode details of images/file locations including my code blocks.

Current Images location path

```
C:\Users\mayro\OneDrive\Documents\Deep_Learning\Dogs-vs-Cats\train
```

Location/path of folders to move the images

```
C:\Users\mayro\OneDrive\Documents\Deep_Learning\Dogs-vs-Cats\train\cat
C:\Users\mayro\OneDrive\Documents\Deep_Learning\Dogs-vs-Cats\train\dog
C:\Users\mayro\OneDrive\Documents\Deep_Learning\Dogs-vs-Cats\test\cat
C:\Users\mayro\OneDrive\Documents\Deep_Learning\Dogs-vs-Cats\test\dog
C:\Users\mayro\OneDrive\Documents\Deep_Learning\Dogs-vs-Cats\valid\cat
C:\Users\mayro\OneDrive\Documents\Deep_Learning\Dogs-vs-Cats\valid\dog
```

3 x Code Blocks

```
os.chdir('C:/Users/mayro/OneDrive/Documents/Deep_Learning/Dogs-vs-Cats')
if os.path.isdir('train/dog') is False:
    os.makedirs('train/dog')
    os.makedirs('train/cat')
    os.makedirs('valid/dog')
    os.makedirs('valid/cat')
    os.makedirs('test/dog')
    os.makedirs('test/cat')
    
    for c in random.sample(glob.glob('train/dog.*'),500):
        shutil.move(c,'train/dog')
    for c in random.sample(glob.glob('train/cat.*'),500):
        shutil.move(c,'train/cat')
    for c in random.sample(glob.glob('train/dog.*'),100):
        shutil.move(c,'valid/dog')
    for c in random.sample(glob.glob('train/cat.*'),100):
        shutil.move(c,'valid/cat')
    for c in random.sample(glob.glob('train/dog.*'),50):
        shutil.move(c,'test/dog')
    for c in random.sample(glob.glob('train/cat.*'),50):
        shutil.move(c,'test/cat')
        
os.chdir('../../')
```

```
train_path = 'C:/Users/mayro/OneDrive/Documents/Deep_Learning/Dogs-vs-Cats/train'
valid_path = 'C:/Users/mayro/OneDrive/Documents/Deep_Learning/Dogs-vs-Cats/valid'
test_path = 'C:/Users/mayro/OneDrive/Documents/Deep_Learning/Dogs-vs-Cats/test'
```

```
train_batches = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=tf.keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input) \
    .flow_from_directory(directory=train_path, target_size=(224,224), classes=['cat', 'dog'], batch_size=10)
valid_batches = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=tf.keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input) \
    .flow_from_directory(directory=valid_path, target_size=(224,224), classes=['cat', 'dog'], batch_size=10)
test_batches = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=tf.keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input) \
    .flow_from_directory(directory=test_path, target_size=(224,224), classes=['cat', 'dog'], batch_size=10, shuffle=False)
```

I have tried changing the code as suggested from a post on reddit (https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/jka6l8/comment/gahncx8/) but still no solution.
Below is the expected output.

Found 1000 images belonging to 2 classes.
Found 200 images belonging to 2 classes.
Found 100 images belonging to 2 classes.

Comment: Have you checked that your images have been moved to the destination? I mean just go to for example C:\Users\mayro\OneDrive\Documents\Deep_Learning\Dogs-vs-Cats\train\cat and check if you have images here after moving.

Comment: No, there are no images